# Can Google send me DMCA notices to takedown private videos on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

Google is notorious for sending [DMCA notices to takedown private videos on YouTube](http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20081029/0355142684.shtml). E.g. on YouTube I often receive DMCA notices for video I took when some music was around: clubs, concerts, bars, street performers, video game screencast, friend singing a popular song while taking a dump, etc. I even [received a DMCA for a video containing white noise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4z_JKIgXPE), so no video is safe.

Can Google send me DMCA notices to takedown private videos on Google+? My Google+ is synchronized with my phones and I use my Google+ account as a backup, hence the question.

Comment: If you're talking about legality, it would be off topic. We can't give or advise on legal issues. If you're asking if they would detect it, then it's within scope.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, let's start with whether they would detect it (i.e. has any user had such issue with his G+ account), question edited!

Comment: Google doesn't send the DMCA takedowns, copyright owners send them to Google who has to comply with the requests. So for private videos no copyright owners will ever see the content to send the DMCA for. The content fingerprinting that YouTube does is not currently active on G+ content as far as I am aware.